# Alternatives to MID400

Tags: arduino, current-measurement, opto-isolator

I'm trying to detect when 24vac is flowing between the "R" and "Y" terminals on my central air conditioner's thermostat using an Arduino Mega2560.

I know from the answers to earlier questions posted here that the MID400 would work well for this purpose... but when I searched for it on Amazon, it looks like it falls into the category of "niche chip that's only available from international sellers, with really long delivery times".

Are there any functionally-equivalent alternatives that might be easier to get quickly and cheaply, either in DIP or breakout-board form? Or is the MID400 a "one of a kind" chip that doesn't really have any nice direct equivalents?

Just to be clear, I don't need to measure the AMOUNT of voltage or current. I just need to be able to observe and detect WHEN 24vac is trickling between the R and Y terminals on the thermostat because a relay inside closed the circuit. The Arduino's logic level is 5v, but a solution that was equally capable of working with 3.3v i/o would be even better (in case I someday decide to replace the Mega2560 with an ESP32).

If it simplifies things, the thermostat circuit's ground/common is available as well.

I considered just trying to stick a relay with a 24vac coil between the thermostat's Y terminal, on the theory that the flowing current would energize the coil along the way to triggering "Y" on the air handler's control board itself, then detecting the state of the relay's contacts using the Arduino. The problem THERE is:

- The thermostat (a Carrier Cor) is directly powered by the R and Common thermostat wires
- Relay coils have nontrivial current draw
- I'm not confident that the combination of the above two concerns wouldn't cause the thermostat to experience brownout & be prone to reboots, or cause  the air handler control board to unreliably detect the closure of R to Y.

For what it's worth, I also have a "clamp-around" SCT-013-010, but after ordering it, I got the distinct impression that there isn't nearly enough current flowing through the wire for that particular sensor to reliably distinguish it from "no current flowing at all".

Comment: you could just get it from [an actual distributor](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/MID400/MID400-ND/31605), but it seems to just be an ordinary optoisolator. When you say "24 VAC is flowing" do you mean you want to detect when there is current, or when there is voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary optocoupler should work fine. Only difference is it will only operate on positive half cycles. So just wait for > 20 ms between detecting pulses before deciding that the thermostat is off.

The circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxvhML.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 is required to protect the LED from reverse voltage.